# Select different coloured lines on R Shiny plot

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app that shows up to 2 different coloured lines depending on which the user has selected to see. However, I keep getting an "unexpected character" error.

I think the problem is in the line `selectInput(inputId = "z", label = "Source", choices = c("social_media", "google_ads"), selected = c("social_media", "google_ads"), multiple = TRUE)` in the code below, as when I substitute `choices` and `selected` with `source`, the graph seems to work (although does not allow the user to select and view different options).

df is a data frame that looks like this:

```
av_purchase_count     days_since_first_use    source
2                     1                       social_media
5                     2                       social_media
4                     1                       google_ads
6                     2                       google_ads
```

...and here is the code I have tried:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
df <- read_xlsx("~/df.xlsx")

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("df"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput(inputId = "x", label = "Days since first use", choices = "days_since_first_use", selected = "days_since_first_use"),
         selectInput(inputId = "y", label = "Average Purchase Count", choices = "av_purchase_count", selected = "av_purchase_count"),
         selectInput(inputId = "z", label = "Source", choices = c("social_media", "google_ads"), selected = c("social_media", "google_ads"), multiple = TRUE)
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("scatterplot")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
     ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y, colour = input$z)) +
       geom_point()
      })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like the end graph to allow the user to select whether they want to see results for `google_ads`, `social_media`, or both (by default, both).

Many thanks, hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by

```
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(
    data = df %>% filter(source %in% input$z),
    aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)
  ) + geom_point(aes(colour = source))
})
```

Variable `input$z` reflects what the user has selected to display(google_ads or social_media or both). It's a reactive vector which will trigger the plot to redraw everytime itself changes. Every time it changes, filter the data frame to preserve only what the user wants to see by `df %>% filter(source %in% input$z)`. Another thing to notice is to color the points based on 'source', you need to use `aes(color = source)` not `aes_string` because you don't want to evaluate source as a variable.

Remember to install and load library(tidyverse), ggplot2 is also part of tidyverse so you can replace `library(ggplot2)` with `library(tidyverse)`. If you really don't want to use tidyverse, then just use `df[df$source %in% input$z, ]` to filter the data

Comment: Oh, except now I get the error message "Error in func(fname, ...) : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object." :-(

Comment: @FPL Did you accidentally delete the last line 'shinyApp(...)'?

Comment: Thanks, yes I had. Time for new glasses... :-)